# TravisCI / Coverity: Warning - No files were emitted

Tags: github, continuous-integration, travis-ci, coverity

I have a medium size github repository for which I configured Travis-CI/Coverity tools. About a month ago my setup had worked just fine: Travis compiled and built my application, and then performed the Coverity scan and I could see the results on my Coverity page.

However, lately, the Coverity analysis stopped working. I looked through the Travis log files and compared to the old logs when the builds were successful and that's what I found:

At the end of the log, the failed version contains the next warning:

> [WARNING] No files were emitted. This may be due to a problem with your configuration or because no files were actually compiled by your build command.
>
> Please make sure you have configured the compilers actually used in the compilation.
>
> For more details, please look at: /home/travis/build/name/repo-name/build/cov-int/build-log.txt
>
> Extracting SCM data for 0 files...
>
> ...

So, **the Travis builds are passing, but nothing is generated for the Coverity**. I checked my Travis config file and it is identical to the commits when the Coverity builds were successful.

For the sake of experiment, I cloned my project repository, rolled back to the version when the builds were successful and set up Travis/Coverity for them. And guess what? Same warning! So, the identical setup that worked in the past (about 35 days ago), does not work anymore. Therefore, I make conclusion, something had changed on the part of Travis since it does not generate certain files.

I was wondering if anyone encountered this issue? and what it could be about? Are there some Travis settings I need to change?

Some additional info: I use CMake to build my project, and it has two dependencies: Qt and OpenSceneGraph (which I have to install for Travis).

This is the approximate script of my `.travis.yml` on my `coverity_scan` branch:

```
language: cpp
os: linux
compiler: gcc
sudo: required
dist: trusty

addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - cmake
      - g++-4.8
  coverity_scan:
    project:
      name: "name/project"
      description: "Build submitted via Travis CI"
    notification_email: email@domain.com
    build_command:   "make -j2 VERBOSE=1"
    branch_pattern: coverity_scan

env:
  global:
    - PROJECT_SOURCE=${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/src/
    - PROJECT_BUILD=${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/build/
    # The next declaration is the encrypted COVERITY_SCAN_TOKEN, created
    #   via the "travis encrypt" command using the project repo's public key
   - secure: "...secure..."

before_install:
  # download Qt
  # ...
  # download OpenSceneGraph
  # ...
  # imitate x server
  - export DISPLAY=:99.0
  - /sbin/start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile /tmp/custom_xvfb_99.pid --make-pidfile --background --exec /usr/bin/Xvfb -- :99 -ac -screen 0 1280x1024x16
  - sleep 3

install:
  # install Qt
  - sudo apt-get --yes install qt55base qt55imageformats qt55svg 
  # compiler
  - export CXX="g++-4.8"
  - export CC="gcc-4.8"
  # install OpenSceneGraph
  # ...

before_script:
  # Qt location
  # ...
  # OpenSceneGraph variables
  # ...

  # create build folder
  - mkdir $PROJECT_BUILD
  - cd $PROJECT_BUILD 
  # cmake command
  - cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/qt54/lib/cmake -DProject_BUILD_TEST=ON -DProject_VERSION=0.0.0 $PROJECT_SOURCE

script:
  - if [[ "${COVERITY_SCAN_BRANCH}" == 1 ]];
    then
      echo "Don't build on coverty_scan branch.";
      exit 0;
    fi
  # compile everything, if not coverity branch
  - make -j2
  # run unit tests
  # ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research and looking through existing examples, I finally made it work. To fix the warning, and, therefore, to make sure files are emitted for the analysis, it is necessary to **explicitly** specify the compiler binary (updated according to the comment) . In my `.travis.yml` I had to add a `build_command_prepend` before the `build_command` of the `coverity_scan` add-on. An example of the final look for that block is as below:

```
# ... 
coverity_scan:
    project:
      name: "name/project"
      description: "Build submitted via Travis CI"
    notification_email: name@domain.com

# ! have to specify the binary (updated, thanks to Caleb)
    build_command_prepend: "cov-configure --comptype gcc --compiler gcc-4.8 --template"

    build_command:   "make VERBOSE=1"
    branch_pattern: coverity_scan

# ...
```

Comment: The problem here isn't that you need to explicitly specify the compiler type, rather the compiler binary itself. `cov-configure --gcc` assumes your binary is named `gcc` or `g++`. Note that if you use certain arguments such as `-m32` or `-m64`, those compilations will fail due to a missing config. You should add `--template` to the cov-configure command line to ensure this doesn't happen.