# Coverity compatibility with gcc-6 on Ubuntu 18.04.1?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, ubuntu-18.04, coverity

We just upgraded our build server from Ubuntu 16.x to 18.04.1, and I can no longer get Coverity to work.

Per [Coverity Scan fails to build <stdlib.h> with _GNU_SOURCE defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434236/coverity-scan-fails-to-build-stdlib-h-with-gnu-source-defined), I have a Docker container on our Ubuntu 18.04.1 machine that installs the `gcc-6` package (there's no other gcc installed in that container -- it's *only* `gcc-6`).

Per [TravisCI / Coverity: Warning - No files were emitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38902793/travisci-coverity-warning-no-files-were-emitted), I also ran the following in my container:  `/coverity/cov-analysis-linux64-7.6.0/bin/cov-configure --comptype gcc --compiler gcc-6 --template`.  This seems to have generated the file `/coverity/cov-analysis-linux64-7.6.0/config/coverity_config.xml`

When I configure / build our software (libfabric, from https://github.com/ofiwg/libfabric) in the container, it builds just fine.  However, if I try to build it via `cov-build`, I get compilation errors.  For example, here's a `cov-build` command to build just a single file from libfabric:

```
# Clear out the Coverity meta data dir, just to be sure
$ rm -rf cov-data
$ /coverity/cov-analysis-linux64-7.6.0/bin/cov-build \
     -dir cov-data make src/fi_tostr.lo
```

Here's a snipit of the relevant output from the `cov-build/build-log.txt` file showing where Coverity failed:

```
[STATUS] Compiling src/fi_tostr.c
/coverity/cov-analysis-linux64-7.6.0/bin/cov-emit --dir=/home/jsquyres/git/libfabric/cov-data --ignore_path=/tmp/cov-0/a35264b27887fab7178c6bf7ab1117a9/cov-configure --ignore_path=/tmp/cov-0/a35264b27887fab7178c6bf7ab1117a9/cov-0/49f277832f55e48469661625f8083203 -w --no_stdarg_builtin --incompat_proto --add_type_modifier=__coverity___fpreg --add_type_modifier=__coverity___float80 --add_type_modifier=__coverity___float128 --no_predefined_cplusplus --gnu_version=60400 --no_predefines --restrict --gnu_carriage_return_line_terminator --no_multiline_string --no_trigraphs --c99 --allow__bool --pre_preinclude /home/jsquyres/git/libfabric/cov-data/emit/394646c6191c/config/5fe0c6b2b8489d2ab05d2434d738b5ac/gcc-config-0/coverity-macro-compat.h --pre_preinclude /home/jsquyres/git/libfabric/cov-data/emit/394646c6191c/config/5fe0c6b2b8489d2ab05d2434d738b5ac/gcc-config-0/coverity-compiler-compat.h --preinclude /coverity/cov-analysis-linux64-7.6.0/config/template-gcc-config-8/../user_nodefs.h --gcc -I . -I include -I prov/sockets/include -I prov/sockets --sys_include /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include --sys_include /usr/local/include --sys_include /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include-fixed --sys_include /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --sys_include /usr/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DNDEBUG -DPROVDLDIR="/usr/local/lib/libfabric" -DRDMADIR="@rdmadir@" -DSYSCONFDIR="/usr/local/etc" -D_GNU_SOURCE -D__OPTIMIZE__ -D__USE_XOPEN2K8 --type_sizes=e16Pdlx8fi4s2 --type_alignments=e16Pdlx8fi4s2 --size_t_type=m --wchar_t_type=i --ptrdiff_t_type=l src/fi_tostr.c
"/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include/stdatomic.h", line 40: error #65:
          expected a ";"
  typedef _Atomic _Bool atomic_bool;
                  ^

"/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include/stdatomic.h", line 41: error #84:
          invalid combination of type specifiers
  typedef _Atomic char atomic_char;
                  ^
```

Does anyone know how to make Coverity understand these types?

Comment: Looks like Coverity does not support the `_Atomic` type qualifier, so it chokes on `<stdatomic.h>`. You can try a hack like `#ifdef __COVERITY__`, `#define _Atomic`, `#endif` before any other includes, or `-D_Atomic=""` compile flag.

Comment: You don't say which version of Coverity you are using. The docs for Coverity contain a table of supported compilers. If the compiler version changed you may need to run cov-configure.

Comment: @PaulFloyd This was now months ago; I don't recall the specific version of Coverity.  It was whatever was current on scan.coverity.com at the time (Oct 2018).  If you read my full problem description, you'll see that I *did* run `cov-configure`.

Comment: Ah yes, and I see that it is version 7.6 from the cov-configure path.

Comment: @PaulFloyd Is there a fix / workaround to make this work?

Comment: Sorry, no. Have you tried using `cov-wizard`? I have no experience with it, but it does have a `Compiler Configuration` pane, but it's probably just a GUI wrapper around `cov-configure`.